# R, calling Matrix package within function

Tags: r, matrix, package, sparse-matrix

I am using the package Matrix to create a sparse matrix inside a function that is contained in my personal R package, say

```
myfun <- function(x, ...){
  d = Matrix(0, 5, 5, sparse = TRUE)
  d[seq(1,25, by=x)] = 1  
  t(d)
}
```

( class(d) is "dgCMatrix" )
If I declare the function in the general environment and I run it from the console, everything works. However, when it is called from the package, I get

```
Error in t.default(D) : argument is not a matrix
```

Essentially R tries to call the t() function from the base environment, instead of the version of t() provided with the Matrix package, that possesses the methods to handle dgCMatrix class objects.

I tried explicitly calling library(Matrix) from within the function, but it does not help.

I had the same problem with another function, colSums(), and I solved it using Matrix::colSums() instead. However I would like to find a more general and practical remedy, instead of specifying the environment for every function.

I stress the fact that if I load the function in the general environment, R correctly loads the functions from Matrix.

Any idea on the source of the problem, or how I can force R to read from Matrix these functions?

Comment: Try ```Matrix::t(d)``` maybe?

Comment: What do your NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files look like for your package?

Comment: @Jesse, they are aware of that approach, as can be seen in how they call `colSums`.

Comment: Opening NAMESPACE I just find 
" exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+") "; I don't really know how to use it.
The Description file reads just:
Package: SDA
Type: Package
Title: SME ABS Data Analysis
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-10-22
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: <myaddress@gmail.com>
Description: SME ABS Data Analysis
License: What license is it under?.    It is not a public package.

Comment: @Giuseppe, Then you need to read up on things like imports and depends and where to include those when creating a package.